# VueJS combine data sources

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have two data sources, one that I created inside my Vue instance and another that I am importing from an api. How do I match the data that I get from the api and combine it with the data I created to display in one table?

HTML:

```
 <div class="ui container" id="app">
  <br>
  <div class="ui two column divided grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ten wide column">
        <table class="ui unstackable green table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Instrument</th>
              <th class="right aligned">Position</th>
              <th class="right aligned">Price</th>
              <th class="right aligned">Total</th>
              <th class="right aligned">%</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in watchlist">
              <td>{{ item.instrument }}</td>
              <td class="right aligned">{{ item.position }}</td>
              <td class="right aligned"></td>
              <td class="right aligned"></td>
              <td class="right aligned"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="six wide column" :attribute="priceData">
        <table class="ui unstackable red table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th  class="center aligned">Coin</th>
              <th  class="center aligned">Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="coin in prices">
              <td>{{ coin.name }}</td>
              <td class="center aligned">{{ coin.price_usd }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have two tables that each displays the data that I would like to combine into one table.

Vue:

```
      new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      watchlist: [
        {  instrument: 'Artbyte', position: 10000 },
        {  instrument: 'Civic (CVC)', position: 1000 },
        {  instrument: 'IOTA', position: 600 },
        {  instrument: 'Basic Attention Token', position: 600 },
        {  instrument: 'Sentiment (SAN)', position: 500 },
        {  instrument: 'TenX', position: 400 },
        {  instrument: 'OmiseGo', position: 100 },
        {  instrument: 'EOS', position: 200 },
        {  instrument: 'Litecoin', position: 30 },
        {  instrument: 'Ethereum', position: 10 },
        {  instrument: 'Bitcoin', position: 2 },
        {  instrument: 'District0x', position: 2000 },
        {  instrument: 'Aragon', position: 60 },
        {  instrument: 'LBRY Credits', position: 200 }
      ],
      prices: []
    },
    computed: {
      priceData: function () {
        var t = this
        axios.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
          .then(function (response) {
            t.prices = response.data
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          })
      },
      getPrices: function () {
        return this.price
      }
    }
  })
```

heres a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/brklyn8900/83y53b2k/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`priceData` should not be a computed; it does not return anything. It should run in the `created` phase.

You can write a computed to combine the two data sources like so:

```
    created() {
        var t = this
        axios.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
          .then(function (response) {
            t.prices = response.data
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          })        
    },
    computed: {
      combinedData() {
          return this.prices.map(c => {
              var obj = Object.assign({}, c);
              var item = this.watchlist.find(w => w.instrument === obj.name);
              if (item) {
                  Object.assign(obj, item);
              }
              return obj;
          });
      }
    },
```

The `map` function makes a copy of each item in `prices`, looks for a matching item in `watchlist` (by comparing `instrument` in the `watchlist` item to `name` in the `prices` item), and if it finds one, it copies the fields from the `watchlist` item into our new object.

Said shorter, it makes a new array whose items are the same as `prices` but with matching `watchlist` items merged into them (where matching items can be found).

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83y53b2k/13/)

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Don't do this.

Comment: @Hybridwebdev Please supply a better answer. Or at least say what's wrong with this one.